# Booting Windows and Linux across two physical drives

Tags: linux, windows, multi-boot, bootloader, mbr

I'm trying to get Windows 7 and Kali Linux bootable on an old laptop, but there are a few considerations that are making it difficult:

1) Windows 7 is on an SSD, while I installed Kali on the original HDD (the laptop has two SATA slots).

2) I eventually want to install another OS (Windows 10) onto the SSD for a triple boot option, and the space won't allow Kali on the SSD as well.

3) I'd also like to encrypt Windows 7 with an existing installation of Truecrypt.

4) Due to a forgotten BIOS password and HDD not being recognized in SATA slot 2, I'm stuck having the HDD as the first one the BIOS looks to boot from.

Currently, Windows 7 and Kali are both running fine on their respective drives, but I can't figure out how to set it up so I can access either one at startup.  I can't see the SSD from Kali to even point Grub to the Windows installation, nor do I really want to since I prefer the Windows bootloader...  It seems like the most suitable option would be to have no bootloader on the HDD, and update the Windows bootloader to select either OS.

The trouble is, I don't know if that's even possible (across drives), if it will survive the Windows system encryption, or if I'll even be able to add a third entry (Windows 10 on the SSD) after encrypting Windows 7.  Does anyone have experience that may help?

Thanks a bunch!